# Magento 2 - PayPal IPN Support

Tags: magento2, paypal, ipn

Does magento 2 support PayPal IPN? I cannot find any document mentioned about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Magento 2 support PayPal IPN (see CHANGELOG).

> Payment improvements:
>
> Implemented support of PayPal IPN protocol HTTP 1.1

Post back to PayPal to check whether this request is a valid one.

\vendor\magento\module-paypal\Model\AbstractIpn.php

```
protected function _postBack()
{
    /*** Code 

    if (empty($postbackResult) || in_array($responseCode, ['500', '502', '503'])) {
        if (empty($postbackResult)) {
            $reason = 'Empty response.';
        } else {
            $reason = 'Response code: ' . $responseCode . '.';
        }
        $this->_debugData['exception'] = 'PayPal IPN postback failure. ' . $reason;
        throw new RemoteServiceUnavailableException(__($reason));
    }
    /*** Code 

    if ($response != 'VERIFIED') {
        $this->_addDebugData('postback', $postbackQuery);
        $this->_addDebugData('postback_result', $postbackResult);
        throw new \Exception('PayPal IPN postback failure. See system.log for details.');
    }

}
```

Hope this answer is useful.

Comment: Is there any log in Magento that I can check if the IPN has been received successfully?